# Rxjs increment loop counter after limit

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have sample code of observable to print some values

```
 sample4Observable() {
    var observable = Observable.create(function (observer) {
      for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
        if (i <= 3) {
          observer.next(i);
        }
        if (i === 4) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            observer.next(i);
            observer.complete();
          }, 5000);
        }
      }
    });
    console.log('just before subscribe');
    observable.subscribe({
      next: x => console.log('got value ' + x),
      error: err => console.error('something wrong occurred: ' + err),
      complete: () => console.log('done'),
    });
    console.log('just after subscribe');
  }
```

**the output is**

```
just before subscribe
got value 1
got value 2
got value 3
just after subscribe
got value 5
done
```

My question is my loop is end when the value reached to 4. So the next value will be 4 instead of 5. why RxJS skip the value 4?

In order to get the value for 4 i can change my code like below. But in above scenario I am little bit confusing. Can anyone explain

```
 setTimeout((i) => {
            observer.next(i);
            observer.complete();
          }, 5000,i);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't relate anything with RxJS anyway, this is the javascript execution happens. Since you're looping up until `i<=4`, count is reaching to 4 and once `i==4` you're firing up a function with `setTimeout`. So as soon `setTimeout` gets registered, it doesn't get evaluate directly. `setTimeout` is async event, browser place it inside something called as `Event Loop`. And wait till all synchronous execution of javascript get over. Since you had `i++` in for loop `i` value becomes `5`. Afterwards all synchronous execution completion. Javascript visit [`Event Loop`](https://blog.carbonfive.com/2013/10/27/the-javascript-event-loop-explained/) to evaluate asynchronous operation(they can be events as well). That time your `setTimeout` evaluate and it wait till `5000`(5 sec), then it gets `i` value as `5` as expected.

The point is even if you set timeout `0` instead of `5000` you will get same result i.e. `i = 5`.

Since javascript is single threaded, it always evaluate synchronous code followed by asynchronous code.

---

There you could pass `i` value as parameter to `setTimeout` function while calling it. Provided `i` value will be available inside the scope of function directly, so that wouldn't checking the global value. Check [MSDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) here

```
setTimeout((i) => {
   observer.next(i);
   observer.complete();
}, 5000,i);
```

Comment: then how about I am getting the value 4 when executing the code directly in javascript  for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
      if (i <= 3) {
        console.log(i);
      }
      if (i === 4) {
        setTimeout((i) => {
          console.log(i);
         
        }, 5000,i);
      }
    }

Comment: @JEMI because [that is the way to pass parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to `setTimeout` function..

Comment: Yes you are right , actually i mistakenly put the code with arguments. in this sample also i am getting 5. I agree it's not related to Rxjs.Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @JEMI pleased to know that, it helped Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

When you set a timeout, the inner function will be executed after the time has passed. When the loop reaches `i === 4` it starts the timeout, the inner function is not yet executed. The loop goes one more round incrementing `i` to 5, then the loop terminates because the condition `i <= 4` is not met anymore. After the 5 seconds have passed (which is after `i` has been incremented to 5), the timeout is fulfilled and the function is executed. Although when the timeout was started `i === 4` was true, now when the timeout function is executed, it is `i === 5`.

This is not directly linked to RxJS. This simpler example should illustrate it. Just run it in your browser console:

```
let i = 0;
setTimeout(() => console.log(`the value of i is ${i}`), 500);
i++;
```

Comment: actually i was expected undefined instead of 5.

Comment: from where rxJS incremented the value?

Comment: It is the loop that increments the `i` after the timeout is started. And after that, when the timeout of 5000 ms finishes, `observer.next(i);` is executed. At that point in time, `i` was already set to 5.

Comment: Have a look at the example I added and run it in your browser console.